# Enable broadcasts between docker containers

Tags: ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-12.04, docker-network

I've been trying to enable some UDP discovery between a few containers.
It tuned out that containers have disabled broadcasts by default, missing brd for inet in:

`$ ip addr show dev eth0
27: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP 
    link/ether 00:00:01:4f:6a:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.12/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Stack:

- host: ubuntu 14.04
- container: ubuntu 12.04
- docker 1.8.3

How do I enable the broadcasts? Here's what I've tried so far:

- `ip link set dev eth0 broadcast 172.17.255.255` gives `RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument`
- same with --privileged container
- same with NET_ADMIN and NET_BROADCAST container capabilities

Comment: As you noted, https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3043 is still pending even for docker 1.9

Comment: Yes, I'm subscribing that ticket. Even thought it is multicast specific it seem to be related to broadcasting by the look of the ipconfig results for other users?

Comment: Have you considered adding service discovery as a capability to your application using tools like consul, etcd or zookeeper? These are easy to run in docker and avoids the need for privileged containers

Comment: Unfortunatelly the application is C++ and I'm not a C++ developer but indeed been thinking of something that will allow to proxy the broadcasts from container A to container B through unicasts until the original issue in docker is resolved. Although the tools you mention are too complex for such task they may become useful later for other concerns so thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of now (Docker 18.06+) UDP broadcasts work out of the box, as long as your are using the default bridge network **and** all containers run on the **same** host (and of course in the same docker network).

Using docker-compose services are automagically run in the same network and thus the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:

  master-cat:
    image: alpine
    command: nc -l -u -p 6666

  slave-cat:
    image: alpine/socat
    depends_on:
      - master-cat
    entrypoint: ''
    command: sh -c "echo 'Meow' | socat - UDP4-DATAGRAM:255.255.255.255:6666,so-broadcast"
```

with `docker-compose up` will show *Meow* on the master-cat (sic!).

If you want to use broadcasts *across* multiple hosts, this is not possible with the default network plugins that docker ships with. -> https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/17814. But a more sophisticated overlay network plugin, such as [Weave](https://github.com/weaveworks/weave) *should* work (I have not tested it...)

Comment: Instead of +1 I'd give this answer a +101 for "showing Meow on the master-cat" !!!