# Docker, UDP and custom subnet

Tags: docker, udp, docker-network

Good day!
I have a problem with docker )

If I run my container within default network, I can see UDP packets, which my container sends. its working well:

```
docker run -d udptest1
```

But, if I create my own network, and container starts in this, I don't see UDP packets. It doesn`t work:

```
docker network create --subnet 192.168.10.0/24 --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name="test10" test10

docker run -d --net=test10 --ip 192.168.10.50 udptest1
```

What do I do wrong? How can I see UDP packets in my custom network?

Thanks!
ps. sorry, if its very easy, its my first expiriecne with docker

Comment: Could you please share udptest1 image or dockerfile

Comment: my problem and reason described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379892/enable-broadcasts-between-docker-containers  (